# Dojo double submittion

Tags: dojo

Yeah! I don't understand it myself!

The following is form that is dynamically loaded into a ContentPane called 'ContentCompanyType'. When the submit button is clicked to submit the form using ajax firefox's firebug shows the form being submitted twice. Once successfully and a second time the form doesn't validate.

I set the first retuned page (the success page) to just simple text so I know the double submit is coming from this page/code.

```
<script language="JavaScript">

    var human = 0;

    dojo.parser.parse(dojo.byId('CompanyTypeForm'));

    dojo.addOnLoad(function(){

        // Select the Company Type if displayed

        dijit.byId('CompanyTypeSelection').set('value',String(1));

        // AJAX get Company Type

        var dijitCT = dijit.byId("CompanyTypeSelection");

        dojo.connect(dijitCT, "onClick", function() {
            human = 1;
        });

        dojo.connect(dijitCT, "onChange", function() {
            if(human) {
                var ctNum = dijitCT.get('value');
                dijit.byId('ContentCompanyType').set("href","companyType/"+ctNum+"/");
            }
        });

        // AJAX Form submission

        var formName = dojo.byId("companyTypeForm");

        dojo.connect(formName, "onsubmit", function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            var xhrArgs = {
                form: dojo.byId("CompanyTypeForm"),
                //handleAs: "text",
                load: function(data) {
                    console.log('submitted');
                    dojo.byId("ContentCompanyType").innerHTML = data;
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    dojo.byId("errorMessage").innerHTML = error;
                }
            }
            //Call the asynchronous xhrPost
            dojo.byId("ContentCompanyType2").innerHTML = "Form being sent..."
            var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);

        });

    });
</script>

<!-- List of all Form Elements -->

<form action="/settings/companyType/1/" method="POST" id="CompanyTypeForm" style="padding: 5px">
    <!-- Select list of all Company Types -->
        <select dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" id="CompanyTypeSelection">
                <option></option>
                <option value="2">Regulators</option>
                <option value="1">Lender2</option>
        </select>
    <label for="id_name">Name</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="name" required="true" value="Lender2" maxLength="60" promptMessage="" type="text" id="id_name" dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" />
    <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an HTML form with a submit button.  That will trigger an HTML submit sans Dojo.  You are also connecting code to the onSubmit event which runs your logic with xhr.  dojo.connect doesn't replace code, it just triggers another method when that method is called.  So, both things happen.  Working as designed.

You may want to define an onSubmit method here that's a no-op or just calls your method.

Comment: do you mean a `<script type="dojo/method" event="onSubmit">` script inside a dijit form. I can do this but there are no example of doing an ajax call inside one of these

Comment: You can just change the button type to 'button' to remove automatic form submission that comes with button of type 'submit'. Try something like: `<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="button" name="submitButton" value="Submit">Update</button>`

Comment: dojo/method is just like a dojo.connect.  The easiest thing is just to put some script in the HTML FORM onSubmit event, or just put in "return false" which prevents the HTML FORM from doing its own submit... or use s dijit.form.Form or do what flammon says.  Too many choices.

Comment: Ended up doing as you said and putting the code inside a `dojo/method > onSubmit` with a `return false;` worked well but unfortunately now the form returned does not use dijit widgets even thought I'm using `dojo.parser.parse(dojo.byId('CompanyTypeForm'));
` hummmmmm...

Comment: got round the dijit's not loading by using the following `dijit.byId("Something").set("content",data);` instead of `dijit.byId("Something").InnerHTML = data`. hope that helps someone in the future

Comment: @Sevenearths, I was thinking of a return false instead of dojo/method, since I think it's called in parallel and not in place of the onSubmit handler.

Comment: The Dijit form widgets should maintain HTML form elements using the NAME as declared in your original HTML, so a normal form submission should contain their values with a normal form submit.  I'm not sure why you need to write your own JS to submit the form here.  What is "Something" in this context?

Comment: The `Something` is a `Div > ContentPane` containing the form and the returned data is loaded into this. I need to have my own JS to submit because it is an AJAx submission (unless there is an another way of doing an AJAX submission I don't know about)